Show side panel on some page, not re-opening
I am using the blow code to show/hide a sidePanel when domainSetting isn't false.  Basically it means that the panel only shows on certain domains.  The issue is that it doesn't re-open the pane.
This is what happens
Tab open and the panel shows as it meets the rule
Navigate to a page that doesn't meet the rule, the panel disappears
Go back to the page where the rule is met, the panel doesn't re-open
console.log("SHOW"); does trigger
Clicking on the extension icon opens the panel
This is the code
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (!tab.url) return;
  const url = new URL(tab.url);
  const domain = url.hostname;
  domainSetting = getSettingInfo(domain)
  if (domainSetting!=false) {
     console.log("SHOW");
     await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      tabId: tabId,
      path: 'sidepanel.html',
      enabled: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log("DISABLE")
    await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
      tabId,
      enabled: false
    });
  }
});

What am I missing?
Thanks


Use info.url everywhere instead of tab.url. 2) Use chrome.sidePanel.open()


Using this - chrome.sidePanel.open({ windowId: tab.windowId}) - gives me errors like this - Uncaught (in promise) Error: sidePanel.open() may only be called in response to a user gesture..  I am using this as my sample if that help explain what I need to do - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.sidepanel-site-specific Thanks
